# Add the page break in the report which the report is the form letter

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'm beginner to design the SSRS which my experience come from Crystal report.
Today, I use report builder to create letter form
and I have add one Tablix and add many row inside under the single group (Just like make form in excel).

But I don't how to add page break on special row (Just like add page break on special row. I try many time but still not work and want to show the picture to you[image]

and I have also try to one more new Tablix  and in the new Tablix Page Break Options check "Add a page break before" and keep together on one page if possible, The final result is the new Tablix content appear at the last page.
(Let say we have 20 records, the new tablix place on Page21)

Can anyone advise how to do it ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Insert a rectangle where you want the page break, then in the rectangle properties select "Add a page break after".